# xmlToJson that can take hints or provide call backs

Tags: java, json, xml

Our api need to provide json output too. So far we are giving xml.
We tried the xml--> json conversion, but, as is well known, it has problems dealing with arrays, data types, name spaces etc.

We don't have xml schema.

Is there a library that does xml --> json but takes hints as to whether a thing is array, what data type, what namespace to use etc. 
or 
can the library provide callbacks so that my logic can feed that information

Comment: How do you create xml, using Java POJO classes?

Comment: I would suggest marshalling from java objects to json instead of generating xml and then json from that...